# Attaching a Rect to imageview so it follows it through infinite animation loop

Tags: android

I cant seem to figure out how to move my **rects** along with an imageview I am animating to use as a hit box. I have it detecting collisions with intersects but it just stays at the starting position of the image.

The first way I cracked at it was by using the `getOnScreenLocation()` and storing that in a variable to use `.offsetTo()` on the **rect** to move it with the image but that only moved the hitbox to the end of the animation and that was it. I have my hitbox movements and checking for collisions inside a seprate thread updating the UI frequently.

So my question is how can I get the **rect** hitbox to just stay attached to the imageview as it is animated across the screen? Any and all advice helps even if its just a method i should look into thank you.

Here is the latest version of my `moveHitbox()`, still it's not functioning correctly.

```
 public void hitBox()
 {
    //declaration of rectangles around each image
    getHits();
    moveHitBox();
    //see if rectangle around rocket intersects enemy ships rectangle
    if (Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect1)||Rect.intersects(myViewRect,
            otherViewRect2) ||Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect3)) {

        check();
        //immunity();
    }
}
public void moveHitBox()
{
    int YYY = (int)enemy_ship.getTranslationY();
    int XXX = (int)enemy_ship.getTranslationX();
    enemy_ship.setTranslationY(YYY);
    enemy_ship.setTranslationX(XXX);
    enemy_ship.getLocationOnScreen(thisLocation);
    enemy_ship2.getLocationOnScreen(thisLocationA);
    enemy_ship3.getLocationOnScreen(thisLocationB);
    x.getLocationOnScreen(thisShipLocation);
    otherViewRect1.union(thisLocation[0],thisLocation[1]);
    otherViewRect2.union(thisLocationA[0], thisLocationA[1]);
    otherViewRect3.union(thisLocationB[0],thisLocationB[1]);
}

// Separate thread that updates the ui thread
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (testByte == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3); // Waits for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

            }catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                finish();
            }
            enemy_ship.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    hitBox();
                }
            });

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You can remove those comments as I have added 'em to your question.